# Div autofill for footers/lack of content

Tags: css, html, height

I asked a question a while ago but I worded it quite badly and ended up confusing everyone, let me retry;

So, I have parent div, child 1, and child 2, and footer.

Parent div, is 100% of the page height, and 1024px wide.

Child 1, is 297px high, and 100% of the parent divs widths.

Child 2 is the content div. It is 100% of the parents height.

Footer is 200px high, and 100% wide of the parent div.

My problem - Making child 2 div 100% of the height of the parent causes an overflow issue on blank documents. Instead of filling up the empty space that is on the page, it actually sets it's height to the original page height that the parent uses.

Solution?

I simply want the div to fill up the empty space, so that the footer remains at the bottom, and the child 1 div background is visible without content

Here is an image;

[image]

The left pic is the issue, the right pic is hopefully what I will be able to achieve.

Code :

```
    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">

            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.gif">

            <hr class="logo">

            <div id="navigation">

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="content">



        </div>

        <div id="footer">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
 * {
margin: 0;
 }

 html, body {
height: 100%;
background-color: #151515;
 }

 hr.logo {
height: 5px;
margin-top: 11px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-color: #ea80d0;
border: 0;
 }

 img.logo {
margin-top: 145px;
 }
 #wrapper {
background-color: green;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -20px;
width: 1024px;
 }

 #header {  
height: 297px;
 }

 #navigation {
margin: 0;  
height: 70px;
 }

 #content {
height: 100%;
background-image: url('images/contentbackground.gif');
margin: 0;
 }

 #footer {
bottom: 0px;
background: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 1024px;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: still quite difficult to understand what your problem.. If you want to make pic 1 look like pic 2; you need to lose those height:100%'s

Comment: If I lose the height 100s, how will the child div (the white and gray one) know to fill in for the rest of the space?

Comment: @Konzine: Could you provide us with a link to your two images used in the code? Without them the result looks very different from your sample images.

Comment: http://throwbackhero.com/index1.php. ignore the ugly colors only there for guides.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but for Child Div2 do not use the width of the parent div.
You can set Child Div2's height **auto**.